# how to use sum and condition in group using spring data mongodb aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

```
db.test.aggregate(
   [ {
       $group:
         {
           _id: "$id",
           "total":{$sum: 1},
           "live" : { $sum : {$cond : { if: { $eq: ["$status",A"]},then: 1, else: 0}}},
           "chat_hrs" :{ $avg: { $subtract: [ "$end_time", "$start_time" ] } }}}]).
```

Kindly help me to write springmvc coding to use mongodb aggregation for the above query.

Comment: Please add what you've tried so far to the post. Here are some examples http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.aggregation

Comment: I tried following code, Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
    project(id","$id")      
          .andExpression("end_time - start_time").as("AvgTime")
          .andExpression("Status", "A").as("lives"),
          
        group("$id").count().as("total")      
        .addToSet("id").as("id")
        .avg("AvgTime").as("chat_hrs")
        .addToSet("lives").as("live"));

Comment: Your spring query is different from your mongo query posted in the question. Can you please show me the actual query ?

Comment: I'm using same spring query.I cannot get "live" field value.Help me to get "live" filed value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the below aggregation pipeline.

```
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation.*;
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.ArithmeticOperators.*;
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.ConditionalOperators.when;
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria.where;

Aggregation aggregation = 
           newAggregation(
               project("id").
                  and(when(where("status").is("A")).then(1).otherwise(0)).as("status").
                  and(Subtract.valueOf("end_time").subtract("start_time")).as("diffTime"),
               group("$id").count().as("total").sum("status").as("live").avg("diffTime").as("chat_hrs"));
```

Generated Mongo Query:

```
[{
    "$project": {
        "id": 1,
        "status": {
            "$cond": {
                "if": {
                    "$eq": ["$status", "A"]
                },
                "then": 1,
                "else": 0
            }
        },
        "diffTime": {
            "$subtract": ["$end_time", "$start_time"]
        }
    }
}, {
    "$group": {
        "_id": "$id",
        "total": {
            "$sum": 1
        },
        "live": {
            "$sum": "$status"
        },
        "chat_hrs": {
            "$avg": "$diffTime"
        }
    }
}]
```